# Animated image does not appear in Chrome using jquery-1.3.2.min.js. It doesn't appear in IE or Chrome if using jquery-1.9.1.js

Tags: jquery, image, animation, using

I can't figure out why an animated image won't appear in Chrome using jquery-1.3.2.min.js. If using jquery-1.9.1.js, it won't appear in IE or Chrome. Am using HTML, css, js. I cleared the cache in Chrome/IE, but that doesn't make a difference. Also tried suggestions in this forum, which are noted below, but didn't work for this issue.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>left.html</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/animatea.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mask">
<div><img id="logo" border="0" src="logo.jpg"></div>  
<div id="subtitle">subtitle</div></div>
</body>
</html>

#mask{  
position:relative;  
/*margin-left: 10px;*/  
width: 400px;  
height: 100px;  
border: 0px solid grey;  
}  
#logo{  
float: right;  /*Tried w/o but made no difference*/ 
margin-left: 100%;  /*Tried different values but makes no difference*/
position: absolute; /*Tried fixed/relative but made no difference*/ 
z-index: 1;  
display: none; /*Tried w/o but made no difference*/ 
}  
#subtitle{
float: right; /*Tried w/o but made no difference*/ 
font-size: 0px;
font-family: verdana;
margin-left: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index:2; /*Tried different number but made no difference*/
}

$(function(){  
//$('#lat1').click(function(){  
var l = $('#logo').width();  
var t = $('#logo').height();  
var speed = 800;  
$('#logo').css({width:0,height:0,display:''});  
moveIt(t,l,s,speed,0);  
});  
function moveIt(a,b,c,d,e){
$('#logo').animate({height:a,width:b,marginLeft:e},d);
aa = a-5;
$('#subtitle').animate({marginTop:aa,marginLeft:e,'fontSize':c},d,function(){
//setTimeout(function(){getBack(a,b,d);a=null,b=null,c=null},500);
});
$('#lat1').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `img` element to have `id="logo"` instead of `id="title"`. Your CSS styles and your JS both refer to an element `#logo` but you have no element with that id.

**EDIT:** I didn't see your update to add the `moveIt()` function until after posting the above. I see now that your `moveIt()` function actually uses `#title` - you need to make that consistent with your other code. (You are also animating a `#subtitle` element that isn't shown?)

Also, I'm not sure that it makes sense to have `#logo` as `float:right` *and* `position:absolute` - try without the `float`.

Comment: Sorry for the edits. I didn't know it had posted already. I tried removing the float, but it made no difference.

Comment: But are you still trying to use `#logo` when there is no such element? `$('#logo').width()` will return `null`. Unless there is more html that you're not showing, you need to go through all of your CSS and JS and fix the references to the non-existent `#logo`.

Comment: The image ID was my mistake moving info to this forum. I double-checked my code and it's correct. It does appear in IE just fine, unless I update the JQUERY. Then it doesn't appear. It doesn't appear in Chrome using the old or new version of JQUERY.

Comment: Then please update your question to be the same as your real code. We can't guess which parts of the question are just typos here and which parts are genuine errors in the real code. The code _as shown_ has the problems I've mentioned.